# Realize un programa en c++ que calcula la moda en unos elementos dados, pero cuando hay mas de una moda solo me da la mayor, quiero que me de ambas

Tags: c++, array

Hola soy un principiante en programación y realicé un programa en c++ que me ayudara a calcular la moda dentro de unos elementos dados, lo primero que hice fue pedir al usuario que ingrese el numero de elementos que desea y posterior a esto pedir que ingrese los elementos mediante un ciclo for.

Después usando el método de bubble sort los organicé de menor a mayor, y por ultimo ayudándome de 2 for los comparo entre si para obtener la moda, el problema surge cuando hay 2 modas, el programa siempre toma la mayor.

Ya hice un par de intentos pero no logro dar con la solución, espero puedan ayudarme:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;



int main() {
   
    double mo, count, max, temp;
    int n, i, j;
    bool swapped;
    
    cout << " >>> Calculando la moda <<<\n";
    cout << " Cuantos valores desea usar?\n " ;
    cin >> n;
    double data[n];
    
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        cout << "Data[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> data[i];
    }
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
            if (data[i - 1] > data[i]) {
                temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[i - 1];
                data[i - 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped == true);
    cout << "Datos organizados: \n" ;
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        cout << data[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    max = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        count = 0;
        for (j = 0; j <= n - 1; j++) {
            if (data[i] == data[j]) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        if (count > 1 && data[i] > max) {
            max = data[i];
        }
    }
    if (max == 0) {
        cout << "No hay moda\n";
    } else {
        mo = max;
        cout << "La moda es " << mo << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo pretendes guardar más de una moda si usas una sola variable para ese dato?

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza un vector en vez de una variable y almacena siempre los dos valores que mas se repiten , junto al numero de repeticiones .
Tras finalizar los bucles , realiza una comprobación en el vector , para quedarte con 1 valor si solo hay una moda , o 2 si hay dos modas .

Comment: se agradecería algo de código en tu respuesta